# HTML/CSS/JS - Overlay backgrounds for modal popups - Issues with

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a semi-opaque overlay to my page that supports multiple modal popups.

The three popup boxes open OK without the need for Javascript, and, with the help of some Javascript, they close by mouse-clicking outside the popups.
Unfortunately, I can't get my overlay to work, without blocking the 'open-modal' buttons. I've tried wrapping the entire 'overlay' div around all the popup boxes, and I've tried keeping the popups outside of the overlay div.

Is there a way to fix this without blocking access to the buttons, and without messing up the 'external close' feature as facilitated by the Javascript?
Three files are attached: ‘.index.html’, ‘style.css’, and ‘modal-script.js’.
Apologies if my terminology is sometimes ‘homespun’, but I’m just and enthusiast doing the best I can.

My code so far is below in this same document. I would be grateful for any suggestions.

---

HTML CODE:
~ Main Document

---

CSS (STYLESHEET):
~ Modal Environment

---

JAVASCRIPT:
~ External Close of Popup Boxes

---

```js
// JAVASCRIPT FILE: js/modal-script.js
// Closes multi-modals in an HTML page

// SET VARIABLES:
var boxArray = ['box1','box2','box3'];
// LISTEN FOR WINDOW EVENT
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
  // LOOP...
  for(var i = 0; i < boxArray.length; i++) { 
    var box = document.getElementById(boxArray[i]); 
    // IF...
    if(event.target != box && event.target.parentNode != box){ 
      // THEN...
      box.style.display = 'none';
    }  // END IF/THEN STATEMENT
  }  // END LOOP
});  // END EVENT
```

```css
/* STYLESHEET FOR MODAL ENVIRONMENT */

/* Pesets */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a:link, a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Halvetica', Arial, sans-serif; /* Default font family */
}

/* MODAL ENVIRONMENT */
.modal { /* Format the 'modal-window', which is the modal environment background containing the 'modal-box(es)' */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}

.modal-content { /* Framework and default settings for popup boxes */
  position: absolute;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 1em;
  display: none;
}

.modal:target { /* Where '.modal' is the target, make it visible */
  display: block;
}

.modal:target .modal-content { /* Where 'modal-content' inside of 'modal' is the target, make both visible */
  display: block;
}

/* MY POPUP BOXES */
#box1 {
  
}

#box2 {
  
}

#box3 {
  
}

/* Formatting: */
.button {
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
}

.type_1-button {
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000;
  margin: 20px;
}

.type_1-button:hover {
  background: dodgerblue;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Multi-modal</title>
    <script src="modal-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Button controls to trigger pop-up boxes-->
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('box1').style.display = 'block'" class="type_1-button">Open Box 1</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('box2').style.display = 'block'" class="type_1-button">Open Box 2</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('box3').style.display = 'block'" class="type_1-button">Open Box 3</button>
    <!--MODAL CODE-->
    <div id="overlay" class="modal"> <!--Create modal window/environment/background-->
      <!--PROBLEM HERE... WHAT TO DO???-->
    </div> <!--End 'overlay' div and 'modal' class-->
    <!--myBoxes: box1-->
    <div id="box1" class="modal-content"> 
      <h2>Pop-out Interface - Box1</h2> 
    </div> <!--End 'box1'-->
    <!--myBoxes: box2-->
    <div id="box2" class="modal-content"> 
      <h2>Pop-out Interface - Box2</h2>
    </div> <!--End 'box2'-->
    <!--myBoxes: box3-->
    <div id="box3" class="modal-content"> 
      <h2>Pop-out Interface - Box3</h2>
    </div> <!--End 'box3'-->
    <!--END MODAL CODE-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work in the StackSnippet. I can access the buttons with the modals active and close the modal by clicking outside the modal.

Answer (score 2):

Add `z-index:11` to `.modal-content` class and remove `display:none` from `.modal` class or add `display:block` to `.modal` class when clicking button.

[image]

If you want to access 3 buttons also when modal popup is appear add `z-index: 11; position: relative;` in `.type_1-button` class.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add `z-index:-1;` to `.modal` and change some `javascript` as below

```js
// JAVASCRIPT FILE: js/modal-script.js
// Closes multi-modals in an HTML page

// SET VARIABLES:
var boxArray = ['box1','box2','box3'];
// LISTEN FOR WINDOW EVENT
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
 // LOOP...
 for(var i = 0; i < boxArray.length; i++) { 
  var box = document.getElementById(boxArray[i]); 
  // IF...
  if(event.target != box && event.target.parentNode != box){ 
   // THEN...
      debugger;
   box.style.display = 'none';
  }  // END IF/THEN STATEMENT
 }  // END LOOP
});  // END EVENT
document.getElementById("overlay").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
/*STYLESHEET FOR MODAL ENVIRONMENT*/

/*Pesets*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}
p {
    margin-top: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Halvetica'; Arial, sans-serif; /* Default font family */
}

/*MODAL ENVIRONMENT*/

.modal { /*Format the 'modal-window', which is the modal environment background containing the 'modal-box(es)'*/
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 10;
 display: none;
}
.modal-content{ /*Framework and default settings for popup boxes*/
    position: absolute;
    background: #e2e2e2;
    width: 80%;
    height: 60%;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 padding: 20px;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 border-radius: 1em;
 display: none;
}
.modal:target { /* Where '.modal' is the target, make it visible */
 display: block;
}
.modal:target .modal-content { /* Where 'modal-content' inside of 'modal' is the target, make both visible */
 display: block;
}

/*MY POPUP BOXES*/
#box1 {
}
#box2 {
}
#box3 {
}

// Formatting:

.button {
 width: 250px;
 height: 30px;
}
.type_1-button {
 width: 250px;
 height: 30px;
 font-size: 0.9em
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #000;
 margin: 20px;
}
.type_1-button:hover {
 background: dodgerblue;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
}
.modal{
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Multi-modal</title>
    <script src="modal-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  
  <body>
      <!--Button controls to trigger pop-up boxes-->
      <button onclick="document.getElementById('box1').style.display = 'block';document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block'"
          class="type_1-button">Open Box 1</button>
      <button onclick="document.getElementById('box2').style.display = 'block';document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block'"
          class="type_1-button">Open Box 2</button>
      <button onclick="document.getElementById('box3').style.display = 'block';document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block'"
        class="type_1-button">Open Box 3</button>
        
      <!--MODAL CODE-->
      <div id="overlay" class="modal"> <!--Create modal window/environment/background-->
          <!--PROBLEM HERE... WHAT TO DO???-->
      </div> <!--End 'overlay' div and 'modal' class-->
          <!--myBoxes: box1-->
          <div id="box1" class="modal-content"> 
            <h2>Pop-out Interface - Box1</h2> 
          </div> <!--End 'box1'-->
          <!--myBoxes: box2-->
          <div id="box2" class="modal-content"> 
            <h2>Pop-out Interface - Box2</h2>
          </div> <!--End 'box2'-->
          <!--myBoxes: box3-->
          <div id="box3" class="modal-content"> 
            <h2>Pop-out Interface - Box3</h2>
          </div> <!--End 'box3'-->
      <!--END MODAL CODE-->
      
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback, people. I wasn't happy with my own solution, so I took it back to the 'drawing board' with all of your valuable comments in mind.

My code now produces a set of three interchangeable modals with two options for closing - press the 'X' symbol or mouse click the background. I will be looking for the third option of closing by [Esc.] key later. Pleas let me know if you have any recommended methods for closing with the escape key.

The overlay window opens and closes at the right moments without interfering with other elements. I hope this make a worthwhile exemplar for anyone looking for modal solutions.

The code is about to follow.

Thank you all,

Adrian McG

---

```js
// MODAL CODE
// Open and close multiple modal boxes
// Project Title: Muli-modals */

// GET MODAL-OPEN BUTTONS

var modalBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-open"); // Get 'ALL' buttons with the '.modal-open' class
// Make a forLoop to work for 'each' individual modal button...
modalBtns.forEach(function(btn) { // Create a function called "btn" to work in a forLoop for each one that equals 'modalBtns'
 btn.onclick = function() { // On mouse-click, activate the 'btn' function and let it do the following...
  var modal = btn.getAttribute("data-modal"); // Declare and set a variable called 'modal' to have the same attribute...
  //as any element that has the property of 'data-modal' (attached to the modal buttons)
  document.getElementById(modal).style.display = "block"; // ...then get the 'modal' document, stored in 'data-modal',
  //and set its display style attribute to "block", which will display all elements with the '.modal' class
 }; // End function
}); // End forLoop

// CLOSE MODALS: Method 1 - Close by button click 
// Get all butons with the '.modal-close' class
var closeBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-close");

closeBtns.forEach(function(btn) { // Create a function called "btn" to work in a forLoop
 btn.onclick = function() { // On mouse-click, activate the 'btn' function and let it do the following...
  var modal = btn.closest(".modal").style.display = "none"; // ...then get the 'modal' document, and set its display style
  // attribute to "none", which will make all elements with the '.modal' class invisible
 } // End function
}) // End forLoop and function

// CLOSE MODALS: Method 2 - Close by external click on the overllay window
window.onclick = function(e) { // Creat a function named 'e' (for event) to work on mouse-click event
 if(e.target.className === "modal") { // If the target of the mouse-click event is strictly equivalent to the class 'modal'...
  e.target.style.display = "none"; // ...then get set the targeted element to 'none'; or, in other words, make the
  // modal invisible 
 } // End if/then statement
} // End function
```

```css
/* Default CSS */

/* PRESETS */

* {
  margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: 'Halvetica', Arial, sans-serif; /* Default font family */
}
a:link, a:visited { /* Prevents links from automaticilly being underlined, unless otherwide specified */
  text-decoration: none;
}
p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
body {
 margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Main HTML page as starting point */
.container { /* Create a wrapper to center the button objects on screen ...
 ... This obviously will change according to main page layout */
 position: fixed;
 width: 500px;
 height: 300px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 background: aqua;
 padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}

/* MODAL ENVIRONMENT */

.modal { /* This is the modal window-overlay that masks out the page we started on */
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 animation: modal-open .5s;
 z-index: 200;
 display: none;
}

/*MODAL BOXES AND CONTENT*/
.modal-content { /* The modal box that pops up inside the modal window-overlay */
 position: relative;
 background: #fff;
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
 top: 25%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%); 
 border-radius: 15px;
 z-index: 400;
 display: inline-block;
}
.modal-header {
   height: 15%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #284254;
  padding: 5px 15px;  
   border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px; 
   border-style: outset; 
   border-width: medium; 
   border-color: #7B919D;
   border-bottom-style: outset; /* Strengthen shadow at bottom-border bevelled edge */
   border-bottom-width: 4px; /* Strengthen shadow at bottom-border bevelled edge */
   border-bottom-color: #1F323F; /* Strengthen shadow at bottom-border bevelled edge */ 
 display: inline-block;
}
.modal-body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 72.75%;
 color: #7b7b7b7;
 padding: 15px 0;
    background-color: #fff; 
    background: linear-gradient(#fff, #999); /* Adds gradient to the modal box background,...
    from white (top) to light grey (bottom) */
}
.modal-footer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 12.25%;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 5px 15px; 
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 border-radius: 15px;
 color: #1a73e8;
    background-color: #fff; 
    background: linear-gradient(#fff, #999); /* Adds gradient to the modal box background,...
    from white (top) to light grey (bottom) */
}

/*MODAL CONTROLS*/

.modal-open {
 width: 150px;
 height: 30px;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #000;
}
.modal-open:hover {
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: dodgerblue;
 color: #fff;
}
.modal-close {
 position: relative;
 background: #c3c3c3c; 
 width: 42px;
 height: 42px;
 top: -60px;
 left: 38px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 color: #5b5b5b;
 font-size: 2.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 0.7;
 border: solid aqua 5px;
 box-shadow: 2px 4px 10px #2d2d2d;
 float: right; 
 display: inline-block;
}
.modal-close:hover {
 background: #5b5b5b;
 color: #c3c3c3;
}

/*FONTS AND PARAGRAPH SPACING*/
.modal-header-text {
 font-size: 1.15em;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: left;
   color: #00FFFF;
   margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
} 
.modal-heading{
  height: 40px;
   font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: bold;
   color: dodgerblue;
   text-align: center;
  margin: 6px 5px 0 5px;
   }  
.modal-paragraph{
   font-size: 1em;
   color: #000000;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px;
}
.modal-footer-text {
   font-size: 0.9em;
   font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
   margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

/*Footer Anchor Links - /*Anchor-link behaviour in footer*/  
.modal-footer-text a:link {
  color: #6900CC;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color:  transparent;
  }   
.modal-footer-text a {
  color: #6900CC;
  }   
.modal-footer-text a:visited {
  color: #505050;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  }      
.modal-footer-text a:hover {
  color: #0000FF;
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: transparent;
  }   
.modal-footer-text a:selected {
  color: #0000FF;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="dcterms.created" content="Tue, 05 Feb 2019 11:43:55 GMT">
      <title>Multi-modals</title>
      <!--JAVASCRIPT-->
       <!--Microsoft Internet Explorer - Finds free sourcecode to translate old versions-->
           <!--[if IE]>
               <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
           <![endif]--> 
      <!--STYLESHEETS-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/modal-style.css" /> 
      <!--END STYLESHEETS-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <!--BUTTONS TO TRIGGER MODALS-->
    <button class="modal-open" data-modal="search">Search</button>
    <button class="modal-open" data-modal="login">Log-in/Sign-up!</button>
    <button class="modal-open" data-modal="spare">Spare</button>
    </div> <!--End 'container' div-->

    <!--MODAL CODE-->
    
    <!--Modal 1-->
    <div class="modal" id="search"> <!--Overlay window to act as backdrop to the modal box-->
      <div class="modal-content"> <!--Format layout and content of modal box-->
        <div class="modal-header"> <!--Format the modal box header-->
          <h1 class="modal-header-text">Modal: Search eruditeAlpha.com</h1>
          <button class="modal-close">&times;</button> <!--Button to close modal--> 
        </div><!--End modal header-->
        <div class="modal-body"> <!--Format the modal box body content-->
          <h2 class="modal-heading">Search Contents</h2>
          <p class="modal-paragraph">This modal is not yet fully functional...</p>
        </div> <!--End modal body-->
        <div class="modal-footer"> <!--Format the modal box footer-->
          <p class="modal-footer-text">Follow me at 
          <a href="http://adrian-mcglinchey.blogspot.com/" target="blank">
          "Adrian's Write"</a> blog space...</p>
        </div>  <!--End modal footer-->
      </div> <!--End modal content-->
    </div> <!--End 'modal1' overlay/backdrop-->

    <!--Modal 2-->
    <div class="modal" id="login"> <!--Overlay window to act as backdrop to the modal box-->
      <div class="modal-content"> <!--Format layout and content of modal box-->
        <div class="modal-header"> <!--Format the modal box header-->
          <h1 class="modal-header-text">Modal: Log-in / Sign-up!</h1>
          <button class="modal-close">&times;</button> <!--Button to close modal-->
        </div><!--End modal header-->
        <div class="modal-body"> <!--Format the modal box body content-->
          <h2 class="modal-heading">Members' Area</h2>
          <p class="modal-paragraph">This modal is not yet fully functional...</p>             
        </div> <!--End modal body-->
        <div class="modal-footer"> <!--Format the modal box footer-->
          <p class="modal-footer-text">Follow me at
          <a href="http://adrian-mcglinchey.blogspot.com/" target="blank">
          "Adrian's Write"</a> blog space...</p>
        </div>  <!--End modal footer-->
      </div> <!--End 'modal2' content-->
    </div> <!--End 'modal2' overlay/backdrop-->

    <!--Modal 3-->
    <div class="modal" id="spare"> <!--Overlay window to act as backdrop to the modal box-->
      <div class="modal-content"> <!--Format layout and content of modal box-->
        <div class="modal-header"> <!--Format the modal box header-->
          <h1 class="modal-header-text">Modal: Spare</h1>
          <button class="modal-close">&times;</button> <!--Button to close modal-->
        </div><!--End modal header-->
        <div class="modal-body"> <!--Format the modal box body content-->
          <h2 class="modal-heading">Keep in Reserve</h2>
          <p class="modal-paragraph"> This modal is not yet fully functional...</p>
        </div> <!--End modal body-->
        <div class="modal-footer"> <!--Format the modal box footer-->
          <p class="modal-footer-text">Follow me at <a href="http://adrian-mcglinchey.blogspot.com/"
          target="blank">
          "Adrian's Write"</a> blog space...</p>
        </div>  <!--End modal footer-->
      </div> <!--End 'modal2' content-->
    </div> <!--End 'modal3' overlay/backdrop-->
      
    <!--JAVASCRIPT CODE FILE-->
    <!--External closing of modal popup boxes-->
    <script src="js/modal-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

---

With that all said, feel free to comment constructively, people, and please don't be too harsh on me if I've made mistakes; I am a web development enthusiast, not a webGuru.

Thanks once again,

Adrian McG